# An Python syntax error in my script

Tags: python, syntax

```
text = open(name + ".txt", "w")  

text.write(con_person + "\n" + con_key_words_list+ "\n" + con_person_rand + "\n" + con_person_rev_rand + "\n" + con_person_up_rand + "\n" + con_person_up_rev_rand + "\n" + con_key_words_list_rand + "\n" + con_key_words_list_rev_rand + "\n" + con_per_per + "\n" + con_per_perrev + "\n" + con_per_perup + "\n" + con_per_kw + "\n" + con_per_kwr + "\n" + con_per_brith02 + "\n" + con_per_brith04 + "\n" + con_per_brith06 + "\n" + con_per_brith68 + "\n" + con_per_rev_brith02 + "\n" + con_per_rev_brith04 + "\n" + con_per_rev_brith06 + "\n" + con_per_rev_brith68 + "\n" con_kw_per + "\n" + con_kw_per_rev + "\n" + con_kw_per_up + "\n" + con_kw_per_up_rev + "\n" + con_kw_kw + "\n" + con_kw_kwr + "\n" + con_kw_brith02 + "\n" + con_kw_brith04 + "\n" + con_kw_brith06 + "\n" + con_kw_brith68 + "\n" + con_kwr_kwr + "\n" + con_kwr_kw + "\n" + con_kwr_brith02 + "\n" + con_kwr_brith04 + "\n" + con_kwr_brith06 + "\n" + con_kwr_brith68)

text.close()
```

***E0001:invalid syntax (, line 259)***
I don't see anything wrong in this line please help.

Comment: Please add your full code

Comment: Code is too long for display.

Comment: A hint for finding syntax errors in really long lines: break it up in many lines. Then the error message will point at the smaller part where the error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
con_per_rev_brith68 + "\n" con_kw_per + "\n" +
```

to

```
con_per_rev_brith68 + "\n" + con_kw_per + "\n" +
```

When writing your code in long lines it makes it hard to catch things like this aswell

Ex:

```
    con_per_rev_brith04 + "\n" + 
    con_per_rev_brith06 + "\n" + 
    con_per_rev_brith68 + "\n" 
    con_kw_per + "\n" +
```